# Model Creation Freezing Django (or Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```py
class AllowedUser(models.Model):
    PLACE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Loc1'),
        (2, 'Loc2'),
        (3, 'Loc3'),
        (4, 'Loc4'),
        (5, 'Loc5'),
    )
    
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8, unique=True, default=generate_unique_id)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    place = models.IntegerField(choices=PLACE_CHOICES)
    current_version = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="0.0.1")
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id + ' - ' + self.name
```

And when I try it in shell, or even in runtime with DRF, it just does nothing.

In DRF, it stops with no error right after `serializer.save()`, in Shell it freezes (not actually freeze, but waits for something) right after `AllowedUser(...Data...)`. I'm using SQLite3 as database.

I actually don't know what's the root problem here. Anyone got an idea on what's causing it to hold?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem started on an earlier snippet that I didn't post, this function:

```py
def generate_unique_id():
    timeout = 0;
    while True:
        timeout += 1;
        # Generate a random 8-character alphanumeric string
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits  # Include both letters and digits
        new_id = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(8)).upper()
        if len(AllowedUser.objects.filter(id=new_id)) == 0:
            return new_id
        else:
            continue
```

The corrected version shown above uses `AllowedUser.objects.filter`, while the error-causing one was using `AllowedUser.objects.create` and missing a not null parameter.